# eslint: disallow inline if-statements

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there an eslint rule to disable

```
if (foo === 'bar') throw new Error('Foo is bar');
```

and instead suggest/require

```
if (foo === 'bar') {
  throw new Error('Foo is bar');
}
```

Comment: This seems like what you want: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/curly

Answer (score 3):

You want eslint native [curly rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/curly):

```js
rules: {
  curly: 'error',
},
```